# Proving $\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{(\partial_x+i\partial_y)(\phi(x,y))}{x+iy}\ \mathrm d(x,y)=c\phi(0,0)$ for $\phi$ Schwartz

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{(\partial_x+i\partial_y)(\phi(x,y))}{x+iy}\ \mathrm d(x,y)=c\phi(0,0)$$ for $\phi\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^2)$ for some constant $c$. I can see that $(x+iy)^{-1}$ is  smooth and bounded away from the origin, while it has finite integral over the unit ball. Hence by dominated convergence (using that $\phi$ is Schwartz), we can write $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{(\partial_x+i\partial_y)(\phi(x,y))}{x+iy}\ \mathrm d(x,y)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\mathbb R^2-B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{(\partial_x+i\partial_y)(\phi(x,y))}{x+iy}\ \mathrm d(x,y)$$

Away from $(0,0)$ we have $(\partial_x+i\partial_y)(x+iy)=0$.

After this, to manipulate the integral, I'd like to use some divergence formula/ integration by parts formula, and was wondering if we could make sense of something like the following: \begin{align*}&\phantom=\int_{\mathbb R^2-B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{(\partial_ x+i\partial_y)(\phi(x,y))}{x+iy}\ \mathrm d(x,y)+\int_{\mathbb R^2-B_\epsilon(0)}(\partial_x+i\partial_y)\left(\frac{1}{x+iy}\right)\phi(x,y)\ \mathrm d(x,y)\\&=\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\frac1{x+iy}\phi(x,y)\cdot \mathbf n\ \mathrm d(x,y)\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}\phi(\epsilon,\theta)e^{i\theta}\epsilon\ \mathrm d\theta,\end{align*} which would be $\approx2\pi\phi(0,0)$ for $\epsilon$ small, by continuity of $\phi$. Then the second integral in the first line of the previous display equals zero since on the domain $(\partial_ x+i\partial_y)(x+iy)=0$. Is such a divergence type formula justified? If not, how to calculate this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divergence theorem exists in a complex analytic form and looks like this

$$\int_{\partial\Omega} f\:dz = 2i\iint\limits_{\Omega} \partial_\bar{z}f\:dx\wedge dy$$

In this case, the integrand is $$\frac{2\partial_{\bar{z}}\phi}{z}$$ which means the proper boundary integral would be

$$\frac{-1}{2i}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0,0)} \frac{2\phi}{z}dz$$

which accounts for the proper orientation. From here plugging a parametrization and taking limits is justified through dominated convergence.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! One minor typo: in your last display, you mean $\partial B_\epsilon(0,0)$, right? And it holds that $\partial_{\bar z}\frac\phi z=\frac{\partial_{\bar z}\phi}z$ because $\frac{\partial}{\partial_{\bar z}}z=0$?

Comment: @Vaclav yes that's right :) You can check for yourself that $$\partial_{\bar{z}}z \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x+i\partial_y)(x+iy) = 0$$